# Two divs side by side: how can i make the div that is on the left side go down when it breaks for responsive layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good afternoon friends,

I'm having a problem when building my responsive layout: At the moment, I have two divs positioned side by side for computer displays. When I view the site on mobile devices, the div that is on the right gets the break and goes down (as expected). However, I would like this process to be reversed. Is there any way to make the div that is on the left to go down and the div that is in the right to stay on top?

I am trying to use the "push" and "pull" class, but it is not working quite well because the div "class B", on computer, stay away from the left side of the screen, as if he had declared a margin or padding.

you can see my site here: http://sosejaculacaoprecoce.com.br/right-sidebar/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-9">
        <div class="B">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-3">
        <div class="A">A</div>
    </div>
</div>

my goal is:

on computer:
row______________
| _____  _______ |
| |  a  ||   b  ||
| |_____||______||
|________________|  

on mobile:                
 ____
|  b |
|____|
 ____
| a  |
|____|


WHAT IS HAPPENING ON COMPUTER:
row______________
|        _____  _|____
|       |  a  ||   b  |
|       |_____||______|
|________________|
```

Even using the inspector, there is no margin or padding statement. You know how to solve?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far..

Comment: if possible share a fiddle too..please..

Comment: You might want to take a look at CSS flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your implementation. If you are using a grid system, most of them have the ability to "push" or "pull" elements in the grid. You should set up the content in the order you want it to display on the smallest device and use the "push" and "pull" classes to modify the position.

If you are not using a grid system and are just floating elements, just use `float:right` instead of `float:left`.

**Updated per comment:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">
        <div class="B">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">
        <div class="A">A</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried to use the push and pull classes but its not working quite well, if you could please check the new information that i placed on the question.

Comment: You should actually push A over 3 columns, and pull B back 9 columns. Push and Pull are relative to the starting position. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some code.

However, instead of applying `float: left;` you can also apply `float: right;` on the other container.

Comment: did not worked because i'm using bootstrap, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

A basic, framework-less approach could be to flip the element's float values when a certain window breakpoint is hit:

```
#firstDiv { float:left; }
#secondDiv { float: right; }

@media screen and (min-width:400px) {
    #firstDiv { float: right; }
    #secondDiv { float: left; }
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQFpD/61/).

**Edit:** Since you've now mentioned that you're using Bootstrap, you could achieve that result with the following changes *(assuming you're using bootstrap 3, and you want each panel to take up half of the row when side-by-side)*:

HTML:

```
 <div class="B col-md-6 col-xs-12">B</div>
 <div class="A col-md-6 col-xs-12">A</div>
```

CSS:

```
.A { float: left; }
.B { float: right; }
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nklein/ydtLL8bb/).

Comment: did not worked because i'm using bootstrap, but thanks

Comment: Would have been helpful for you to mention that before. I've updated my answer to suit a bootstrap scenario.